# Fragment inside a ListView - Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to add fragment inside a repeating li component:

```
<ul>
<li wicket:id="listView">HERE GOES MY FRAGMENT</li>
</ul>
```

The code to populate the listview is the following:

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(final org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.Item<Message> item) {
                    Message msg = item.getModelObject();
                    log.info("Adding message fragment to markup: " + item.getMarkupId());
                    item.add(new MessageFragement(item.getMarkupId(), "messageFragment", this, msg));
}
```

The generated expected code is:

```
<ul>
<li .... wicket:id="listView></li>
<li .... wicket:id="listView></li>
....
</ul>
```

But my fragment is not added and I receive the Runtime wicket exception:

> The component(s) below failed to render.  A common problem is that you
>   have added a component in code but forgot to reference it in the
>   markup (thus the component will never be rendered).

Why I cannot use the item markup id as componenent id for my fragment? 
I now this can be easily solved by adding an additional tag on the li:

```
<ul><li wicket:id="listView"><div wicket:id="message"></div></li></ul>
```

And add the markup id "message" to the fragment. But I don't want it. I just want to use the already there <li> to host my fragment, is it even possible?

Thanks guys

Comment: I think this is because fragments simply discards its parent tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution, or better, a workaround.

I do leave the container tag for the Fragment in the <li>:

```
<ul>
<li wicket:id="listView"><div wicket:id="message">FRAGMENT</div></li>
</ul>
```

After that in the MessageFragment I just set in the Fragment constructor to not render the container tag using the **setRenderBodyOnly(true)** function:

```
public MessageFragement(String id, String markupId, MarkupContainer markupProvider, final Message message) {
            super(id, markupId, markupProvider, new Model<Message>(message));

            setRenderBodyOnly(true);
...
}
```

And the result is as expected:

```
<ul>
    <li wicket:id="listView" wicketpath="...listView_1">MessageFragment1</li>
    <li wicket:id="listView" wicketpath="...listView_2">MessageFragment2</li>
    <li wicket:id="listView" wicketpath="...listView_3">MessageFragment3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If youd like to use your li list entry as placeholder for the fragment, you need to at least provide a wicket:fragment for your fragment which should be rendered in placeholder.

but, even if you setStripWicketTags to false which would result in the original wicket:id in your markup, this id will not be equal to the return of getMarkupId() because they will get at least a random suffix. also there is already a component attached to that Id so it is not possible to attach any other components to it

Comment: Hi Marcel, if you set the listview at <ul> level this will cause the ul element to be repeated each time, resulting in the following:
<ul><li>FIRST FRAGMENT</li></ul>
<ul><li>SECOND FRAGMENT</li></ul>
.... which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Damn you are right :/ I am used to working with Loops and my first thought was you missunderstood how listview is working. But afterall I got it wrong. checked my page again and actuelly found a place with listview where it is attached to ul and ul is off course being repeated lol